# Different output of command over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to dump cpu usage of a particular process over ssh using top and I want full command line to be shown.
When I ssh to the server and execute command locally, I see following:

```
remote-server$ top -c -b -n 1 |grep redis-server
 5137 redis-user   20   0 83.5g  23g  884 S 13.7 29.3  13388:28 ./bin/redis-server *:11000
```

But when I execute the same command over ssh, I see following:

```
local-desktop$ ssh news-cache1 "top -c -b -n 1 |grep redis-server"
 5137 redis-user   20   0 83.5g  23g  884 S 13.7 29.4  13388:55 ./bin/redis-server
```

I don't understand why I don't get complete command line (with host and port arguments *:11000) when I run the command over ssh.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

My local desktop is OS X, El Capitan while remote server is centos 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rerun the command with -t option in ssh.

```
local-desktop$ ssh -t news-cache1 "top -c -b -n 1 |grep redis-server"
```

ssh client assigns a tty terminal with limited width when you run commands remotely. The width of the terminal assigned was not enough to show the full line that you are interested in. Adding -t forces a pseudo-terminal allocation. From http://man.openbsd.org/ssh

```
-t Force pseudo-terminal allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Comment: "ssh client assigns a tty terminal with limited width when you run commands remotely" Actually, it doesn't allocate a tty at all by default when you run a remote command.

Comment: Thanks kdeb. After ssh started working, I tried the same command with pssh and then it failed even after allocating the terminal (-X -tt). It seems in case of pssh pseudo terminal width is not enough and finally was able to make it work by setting terminal width as follows: `pssh -i -X -tt -H news-cache1 "stty columns 200;top -c -b -n 1 |grep redis-server"`